# ASP Classic choosing better itinerary

Tags: algorithm, asp-classic, selection, routes, shortest-path

I'm developing a website for posting section in a company, and I'm stuck at the following need:

The company have a several affiliates and each one have different itineraries for sending posts.

For exemple I'm thinking as following:

Unit 1 send just to unit 2, that sends just to unit 3, ...

So, if I want to post something from unit 1 to unit 6, it have to pass through the units 2, 3, 4 and 5. Until this I was able to do with the code that I will but below:

```
<%
origem = int(request.querystring("origem"))
destino = int(request.querystring("destino"))
codcorrespondencia = int(request.querystring("codcorrespondencia"))

set rs = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
set rs2 = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

base = destino
caminho = base

do while not base = origem
rs.open "select * from ESCALAS where codunidade_post = " & base, conexao

    if not rs.fields("codunidade") = origem then
        do while not rs.eof
        rs2.open "select * from ESCALAS where codunidade_post = " & rs.fields("codunidade"), conexao
            if not rs2.eof then
            escalacao = int(rs.fields("codunidade")) & " - " & base & "; " & escalacao 'novas linhas
            base = int(rs.fields("codunidade"))
            end if
        rs2.close

        rs.movenext
        loop
    else
    escalacao = rs.fields("codunidade") & " - " & base & "; " & escalacao 'novas linhas
    base = origem
    end if
rs.close
caminho = base & "," & caminho
loop

response.Write(escalacao)
%>
```

but, if the following situation happens:

unit 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 4 to 5, 4 to 6 and 5 to 6

The code chooses to send from 4 to 5, and 5 to 6, instead of straight from 4 to 6.

How my code can become smart and choose the shortest way?

For testing I put the var ESCALACAO. It shows to me the way that the code pick.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to implement a shortest path algorithm in order to find the optimal route for your posts, as you have multiple routes from 4 to 6 (direct 4->6 and indirect 4->5->6).

See [Shortest Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) on Wikipedia.